# O que há de errado com meu código K-nearest Neighbor em R?

Tags: r, machine-learning

Boa tarde,

por que meu código KNN em R produz "predições" que são iguais as próprias respostas da base de Teste? Ou seja, se mudarmos as respostas da base de testes a "previsão" muda igualmente (e a tabela de previsão acaba sendo sempre de 100% de acuracidade)?

Código:

```
a <- read.csv2("Base Treino.csv")

b <- read.csv2("Base Teste.csv")
a_cl <- a[1:10,4]

pr=knn(a,b,a_cl, k=2)

a_teste_cat <- b[,4]

tab <- table(pr,a_teste_cat)

tab

Base Treino:

100 33  100 0
100 66  75  0
100 100 50  0
100 0   25  100
100 0   100 100
0   0   25  100
0   0   75  100
0   0   0   100
0   33  100 0
0   66  100 0

Base Teste:

100 33  100 0
100 66  75  0
0   0   25  100
0   0   75  100
0   0   0   100
0   66  100 0
```

Comment: Oi Victor, porque você incluiu o conjunto de teste ao treinar o KNN? Uma sujestão é melhorar o nome das variaveis, em vez de 'a', use algo do tipo 'dados_treinamento'.

Comment: Filipe, boa noite. A sintaxe do knn pede que eu insira a base de teste nos parametros... Como você executa?

Answer (score 1):

A sua acurácia está dando 100% porque os dados do seu conjunto de teste estão presente no conjunto de treino. Como o resultado do KNN é medido pela distância entre pontos, e seu conjunto de teste está presente no conjunto de treino, ele vai sempre acertar.

Uma dica extra é, sempre que for otimizar um hiper-parâmetro de um modelo (como o K do KNN), crie um conjunto de validação e ache os melhores valores dos hiper-parâmetros para o conjunto de validação. Só depois desse processo use o modelo para o conjunto de teste. Com isso você vai poder simular a realidade, treinando e otimizando o modelo com dados conhecidos, e testando-o para dados desconhecidos.